# Java command line launcher

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, launch

So I'm trying to launch a jar from the command line using these arguments similar to these:

```
java -cp "path/test.jar;path/lib.jar" -Djava.library.path="path/another_lib.jar" net.test.Test
```

(net.test.Test is the main class) Which gives me a NoClassDefFoundError Exception (for net/test/Test).

This seems to work fine for other people, so I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: Which jar is that class in,  and is definitely getting referenced by the classpath successfully? If it's not in a .jar and local to the current directory you'll need a `;.` at the end of the classpath.

Comment: It's in test.jar, so am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `-Djava.library.path=/something` tells the JVM where to find native libraries -- i.e., DLLs. It has nothing to do with finding `jar` files, so if you're using that flag to locate `jar` files, that's going to be a problem right there.

Otherwise, this is fine. You need to make sure all of those paths are correct, and the jar file containing `net.test.Test` really does contain the class in question, and inside the jar file the `Test.class` file is in a `test` directory in a `net` directory.

As Rup points out in a comment, if there are any classes in your current directory that you need to pick up, you'll want to add an entry for ".", the current directory, to the `-cp` argument.

Comment: the Djava.library.path does find native libraries. Sorry, I should have specified.

Comment: @Josh, did you find your problem?

Comment: no I didn't, I can give you my exact parameters if necessary.

Comment: I bet your parameters are fine, @Josh -- I'd carefully examine your jar file, though, to make sure the class is stored properly.

Comment: well, the "path" part of my parameters is actually the exact file path from my hard drive (/Users/Josh/Library/Application Support/) I'm not sure if that can be a problem or not. net.test.Test is in test.jar.